# Representing $X^\top MX$ as a function of $MX$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, transpose

When can we write $X^\top MX$ as a function of $MX$?

Here $M$ is a fixed symmetric matrix and $X$ is a variable matrix, which may be non-square also.

**My attempts**

When $M$ is idempotent, then we are done, because then $X^\top CX = (CX)^\top(CX)$. But can we have a weaker sufficient condition? Is there a necessary and sufficient condition??

Comment: This will hold whenever $M$ is invertible since we can write $X^TMX = (MX)^TM^{-1}(MX)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Yeah, I also thought of that, but the problem is that the rank of $M$ is unknown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, this will always hold.  Let $P$ be an invertible matrix such that
$$
P^TMP = \pmatrix{I_p\\ &-I_q\\&&0_r}.
$$
Let $Y = P^{-1}X$. We have
$$
MX = P^{-T}(P^TMP)(P^{-1}X) = P^{-T} \pmatrix{Y_1\\-Y_2\\0}.
$$
On the other hand
$$
X^TMX = Y^T(P^TMP)Y = \\
\pmatrix{Y_1^T & Y_2^T & Y_3^T}\pmatrix{I_p\\ &-I_q\\&&0_r}\pmatrix{Y_1\\Y_2\\Y_3} = \\
Y_1^TY_1 - Y_2^TY_2.
$$
Conclude that 
$$
X^TMX = \begin{bmatrix}Y_1^T & -Y_2^T&0\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}I_p\\ &-I_q\\&&0_r\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}Y_1\\-Y_2\\0\end{bmatrix}
\\= [(MX)^TP](P^{-T}MP^{-1})[P^T(MX)]
\\ = (MX)^T(P^{-1}P^T)^TM(P^{-1}P^T)(MX).
$$

Comment: I could not understand the second last step. How did you get that expression for $X^\top MX$??

Comment: @Martund I've added something in to clarify things.  Let me know if it's still unclear

Comment: Now I understood, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter version: let $M^+$ be the [Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $M$. Then
$$
X^T M X = X^T MM^+MX = (MX)^T M^+ (MX)
$$
In contrast to $M^{-1}$, $M^{+}$ always exists (even for non-square matrices) and satisfies $M=MM^+M$

Comment: Nice proof, thank you